# Add A Block To An Existing Tab Programmatically

Tags: blocks, ce-1.9.0.1

I'm trying to add a block to an *existing* tab on the product view page in Magento, programmatically.

The tab is the pre-existing **description** tab, around line 185 of the catalog xml file at **app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/catalog.xml**

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_description" name="product.description" as="description" template="catalog/product/view/description.phtml">
    <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
    <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Description</value></action>
</block>
```

I'm using a custom module and trying to *inject* my block after the description content, in the same tab. Here's the code:

```
class My_Details_Block_Product extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    protected $_template = 'details/product_details.phtml';

    protected function _prepareLayout() {
        if ($addToTabBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('product.description')) {
            $addToTabBlock->insert($this, '', false, 'details');
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

There are no errors available in any of the logs, but the block simply doesn't appear. I've also tried to use the *append* method:

```
$addToTabBlock->append($this, 'other');
```

But get the same (blank) result.

How can I insert a block to the existing tab? Thanks.

Comment: are you sure, you block instantiates when page loads. put `die();` inside your `preapareLayout()` and give me the result

Comment: @programmer_rkt yes, it instantiates. `die();` produces a blank page. Also, `var_dump('anything');` inside the `if(..)` loop spits out on the page. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this. I didn't test this code.

```
class My_Details_Block_Product extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    protected $_template = 'details/product_details.phtml';

    protected function _prepareLayout() {
        if ($addToTabBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('product.description')) {

            //sets this block as child to description block
            $addToTabBlock->setChild( 'my.custom.block',$this->getLayout()->createBlock( $this,'my.custom.block',array('template' => 'details/product_details.phtml')));
        }
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }
}
```

You may need to call this block  in `description.phtml` as like this

```
<div><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('my.custom.block');  ?> </div>
```

in the desired position

Comment: I *did* need to call the block in the `phtml` file. Thx for the help

Comment: what about the `_prepareLayout()` method ? Your code worked?

Comment: did you try my code? Is that worked ?

Comment: Yes, your code worked, thx.

Comment: I would like to know, how did you make trigger your block when product view page loads?

Comment: I combined @Samuel Coman's answer, using xml layout update file; I added the block in `<catalog_product_view>` section.

Comment: oh ok you have your block included in layout file, right ?

Comment: Yes, I included the block there.

Answer (score 1):

You could do that or you could try another way. Add a [layout update xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19513002/magento-add-custom-layout-updates-for-module) and in that xml file add a layout update:

```
<reference name="description">
   <block type="core/template" name="a_nice_name" template="some/path/to/details/product_details.phtml" />
</reference>
```

Comment: Thanks @Samuel, incidentally that doesn't work for tabs (or for me!). Also, your block is missing a self-closing tag `/>`.

Comment: It surely works. Magento is just stubborn if something is slightly wrong. Anyway, enable template path hints and see what blocks are loaded in that specific area. Also, check if your module is loaded and also if your xml is loaded. If all is ok by now, it's just an xml error. For that, you can check your var/log.

Comment: @SamuelComan : You idea is correct. But he needs to add **his own block** rather that `core/template`. But he can addopt this method to add his block. Also he need to call his block in `description.phtml` also

Comment: Thanks @Samuel, I believe you, but still doesn't work for tabs on my stack; maybe a theme issue. BTW, your reference tag should be `<reference name="description">`, for future visitors.